# Need to rename mulitiple files recursively using zmv

Tags: zsh

So I'm battling with a script at the moment. I'm using zsh. I've tried various combinations, but not coming right. Trying to change file names recursively. So basically I have a variable: file1.
What I'm trying to do is something like this:

```
zmv -W ${file1}/'**/*(test)*' ${file1}/'**/*red*'
```

This should change any file or folder in subdirectories recursively from test to red. Hence:
if $file1= /var/log then it should change:

/var/log/jump/green**test**.txt to /var/log/jump/green**red**.txt

also

/var/log/jump/1/1/**test**/**test**.xyz to /var/log/jump/1/1/**red**/**red**.xyz

Basically if I did a search:
`ls **/*test*` it would list all the files and folders recursively that had the word 'test' contained within them. With the zmv solution, I'd like to "find" those instances and change test to red.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope you try these things first with `-n`....

Aside from this, the only part which looks wrong to me are the parenthesis around `test`. You introduce a new pattern variable for something which is not a wildcard, but your `-W` alreay implicitly introduces groups and references. Hence I would try it with

```
zmv -Wn $file1/'**/*test*' $file1/'**/*red*'
```

and if it works, remove the `-n`.

Comment: Hi @user1934428.
Thanks. I had used the -n so all good :)
Ok, so I had been trying to substitute a different combination.....and had in fact tried your solution, however it didn't work....seems that `zmv -Wn $file1/'**/*test*' $file1/'**/*red*'` works however `zmv -Wn $file1/'**/*good*' $file1/'**/*red*'` has an error as follows `zmv:239: no matches found: /var/log/**/(*)good(*)(odon)`
Have actually found I can use `g` `go` `goo` but as soon as I want `good` substituted, it gives the error....very strange indeed!

Comment: Where did you get the _odon_ part from? Before trying the zmv, did you check whether an  `echo $file1/**/*test*` returns sensible files?

Comment: Hi so that string with the odon bit, is actually what gets output from the shell when I try to run the command with good. As mentioned, it works but not with good as a string....so strange...
Try your side, and substitute test with good...

Comment: Hi, accepting your answer. Seems like one of the tests I'd done, had changed the filename.
That error comes up if it can't find the string.....stange as it threw me off, because of the brackets still being around the `*` ....
Thanks for the assistance